# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

В те же 90-е годы, когда Государство ставило задачи не на импортозамещение, а на конверсию (,) нефтегазовые компании развернули вполне эффективную программу импортозамещения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В те же 90-е годы, когда Государство ставило задачи не на импортозамещение, а на конверсию, нефтегазовые компании развернули вполне эффективную программу замещения импортного оборудования.

Запятая закрывает придаточное предложение, также желательно не повторять слово "импортозамещение". И почему "государство" с прописной буквы?